# SpringMVC - Error using mvcUrl - Missing WebApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I have basic Rest Controller and JSP. I want to be able to access the URL in the request mapping annotations from the JSP. I noticed that mvcUrl in Spring MVC 4.1 allows you to do that. But I run into an error when I try this:

When I open `localhost/test.jsp`. I see this in the browser:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.ELException: Problems calling function 's:mvcUrl'
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:556)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)    
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)    
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    .....

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot lookup handler method mappings without WebApplicationContext
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.getRequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:521)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:330)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName(MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java:313)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ....
```

Here is some sample code that I used

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooRestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
           return "hello";
    }
}
```

JSP File - test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>

<a href="${s:mvcUrl('FRC#hello').build()}">Link to Hello</a>
```

What could be setup wrong?

When I hit `localhost/foo/hello` I do get back a json string  `"hello"`. Doesn't that mean the dispatcher servlet is working fine and the `WebApplicationContext` is actually setup properly?

Comment: If it returns "hello" then you can say "Hi", no coding is required.

Comment: No, it means you should've used `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you.

Comment: What does using @Controller have to do with the jsp?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your description and assumed part of your diagnosis was the problem.

Comment: try using model and view .it will solve your problem eg:  return new ModelAndView("hello");

Comment: I think  some configuration related to  HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy is missing in application context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is: you only defined controller handler for `/foo/hello`, but not for `/test.jsp` . Try adding a new controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class GeneralController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
           return "test"; // put the view name here. You won't need ".jsp" because it would be automatically added by the view resolver in the configuration below
    }
}
```

and make sure similar code exists in your configuration, so that the system know where to look for your view

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/[Your_JSP_FOLDER]"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Agreed error came from: Assert WebApplicationContext  == null, in MvcUriComponentsBuilder.java because it cannot resolve ressource view

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. I had tried this earlier. Because I realized that the jsp file was not being rendered properly by spring MVC perhaps because i never ran it via the dispatcher servlet but simply served it up. But, back then, i had still gotten the same error. Not sure what i had done wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Well written answer. Accepting this. You get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This not a problem with your configuration file as you are using 
@RestController annotaion in your controller which is a convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody . as you may know annotating your class with @ResponseBody will return you back the json response from the method of the coltroller which is the expected behavior in this case.

If you want to get the jsp file what you should have used is

1.use @Controller instead of @RestController 
2.Assuming you have configured view resolver with prefix and suffix for jsp page and return test string from the method because your jsp file name says it's name is test .

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Good answer. (+1) You are right. The view/jsp needs to be resolved via the spring servlet instead of being just served up using the default tomcat servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a configuration issue we have also faced similar kind of issues the only  solution was to use modelandview instead of returning the view as string in the controller